# Htaccess parameter overwrite + allow additional params?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I have a rule in my .htaccess file to overwrite ugly parameter urls with clean paths.

Here is an example:

`RewriteRule ^landing(/)?([0-9]+)?(/)?$ landing/index.php?intPage=$2`

So when someone goes to /landing/3, it would load the index.php page passing intPage parameters as 3.

Very simple.

However, I'm using techniques to trace Google Analytics referals, so I need to tack parameters onto this URL:

For example:

`/landing/3?kt_type=ad&kt_st1=adwords&kt_st2=prize_a_us.en`

The problem is that, I don't know how to retrieve the parameters that are tacked onto the URL, since the URL has already been overwritten and now I can't retrieve kt_type, kt_st1 etc.

Any idea on how to make it possible so I can still tack parameters to already overwritten URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [QSA flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa). Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^landing/?([0-9]+)?/?$ landing/index.php?intPage=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

From official docs:

> QSA - Appends any query string from the original request URL to any
>   query string created in the rewrite target

Comment: What is L,NC here?